# Dictionary of Actions - Include Action parameters

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the key is a string, and the value is an Action that takes two parameters (a string and a byte array)

`private Dictionary<string, Action> handlers = new Dictionary<string, Action>();`

Then a function to add a value to the dictionary

```
public void Bind(string key, Action<string, byte[]> cb)
{
    handlers[key] = cb;
}
```

However the error is "Cannot convert System.Action to System.Action"

How can I change the definition of the dictionary to include the Action parameters?

Comment: private Dictionary<string, Action<string, byte[]>> handlers = new Dictionary<string, Action<string, byte[]>>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the same type in your dictionary with what you want to assign:

```
private Dictionary<string, Action<string, byte[]>> handlers 
    = new Dictionary<string, Action<string, byte[]>>();
```

Then your `KeyValuePair` `cb` will have the same `TValue` of your `handlers`:

```
public void Bind(string key, Action<string, byte[]> cb)
{
    handlers[key] = cb;
}
```